# reset uid counter

Tags: linux, users

In freshly installed system UID usually starts with **1000** while creating new user using command

```sh
useradd dummy
id -u dummy # 1000
```

which can be modified by `-u, --uid` option

```sh
useradd --uid 9000 dummy9000
id -u dummy # 9000
```

but if I create the user again without `--uid` it start uid increment after **9000**

```sh
useradd dum
id -u dum # 9001
```

How do I reset the **UID** counter?

**UPDATE**

actually tested out suggestion by @schily, I guess it takes max value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

```
The UID defaults to  the  next  available
(unique)  number  above  the  highest  number  currently
assigned. For example, if UIDs 100,  105,  and  200  are
assigned,  the next default UID number will be 201.
```

Comment: can i ask man which section?

Comment: I checked the original UNIX man page from section 1m: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1m/useradd.1m.html `useradd` has  been introduced 36 years ago.

Comment: I was checking current man page `useradd (8)` , couldn't find the phrase! `useradd` is older than me!